# Selenium, struggle closing a window after checking 100+ boxes across 20 pages, standardized code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

On the following website https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1
For different counties, I will have to select all the HISCO Occupation variables, which means clicking the "more variables" button and checking each box on every page. The number of pages of these HISCO Occupations is variable and depends on the county.

What I've done so far is code in the following format, checking each box and then clicking on the next page, for the maximum number of pages (20 pages):

```
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[5]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[6]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[7]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[8]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[9]/label/input').click()
webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[10]/label/input').click()

webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/ul/li[9]/a').click()
```

When I try and run this on an example with only 17 pages, the checking each box and flipping pages part works great. My issue lies in clicking the "Apply" button.

In earlier code, only selecting one HISCO Occupation, the following code worked in clicking the Apply button:

```
WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Apply')]"))).click()
```

This same command doesn't work in this setting. It only works if I have the exact tailored boxes ticked in my code (if I have 17 pages, my code must only span 17 pages), no extra. As I have to do this for each year and each county, I cannot tailor the code and need a general strategy to solve this.

As always, thank you to anyone who helps me!!

IDLE Sends this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jessi/Desktop/Selenium/RA_TASK1_ALL_HISCO_CHECKED.py", line 326, in <module>
    webD.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[6]/label/input').click()
  File "C:\Users\jessi\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\jessi\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\jessi\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\jessi\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[6]/label/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB Edit: I need to tick all boxes of the HISCO variable, but the number of these boxes and pages varies depending on the county I chose. The code I have right now works perfectly only if it contains the exact number of pages/boxes to tick. As there is many different counties I cannot have tailored code for each situation. I'd love insight in how to solve this issue... Looping seems very complicated, since there are 200 lines...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple similar elements, try `find_elements_by_xpath`.

`webD.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div//label/input')` would return a list all the input elements you want to click regardless of how many of them are listed. Then you can click them all in a `for` loop.

You may want to use better `xpath` expressions, like `'//div[@class="modal-body ng-scope"]//input[@type="checkbox"]'`

So basically you want something like this on each page:

```py
input_elements = webD.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-body ng-scope"]//input[@type="checkbox"]')
for elem in input_elements:
   elem.click()
```

Comment: Right! Makes so much sense! Thanks for the advice. Weirdly neither xpath in the input elements form is checking the boxes...

Comment: Yes indeed, your suggestion makes a lot of sense and I see how it is more efficient. It doesn't check the boxes though, and I've tried fiddling around a bit... can't figure out why it doesn't so far. Thank you for you help

Comment: I am sorry to hear that the check does not happen. `input_elements` should be a list of input elements which should be clickable and tick the boxes on/off.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your help, and the good advice.